# Keeping site at fixed size using viewports?

Tags: html, css, size, viewport, resolution

I want a page with a fixed pixel size to always have the same percantage hight.

Means when I have a div with a hight of 1500px and view it on a 1366x768 screen the whole 1500px div should still be visable completely.

```css
.fix{
width:400px;
height:400px;
background-color:green;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix"></div>
```

Comment: Stop using `px` and start using `%` - because that's the only way you'll get a bigger-than-the-visible-screen-area div to stay visible.

Comment: lookup css relative units

Comment: a lot of devices have a much smaller screen size/resolution than that

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "vh" unit to set the height of your div relative to the viewport:

.fix { height: 50vh } will set the div's height to 50% of the viewport.

Or you can use % instead of px - in this case, just make sure to set the body and html height to 100%.

Comment: the problem is that I made a whole site using px, now you cant poperly view it in smaller resolutions since it should be a site on which you are not able to scroll down. 

I'm looking for something which acts like browser zoom, just making everything a bit smaller on smaller resolutions. 

site: http://palmira-lopez.de